# Fill small tables with fixed header titles with data from different cells

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

For example: I have this table:

[image: Normal Table in Sheet 1]

I want to fill this source data into small forms / pattern like this picture below, so I can be able to print the like that,

[image: Target View in Sheet 2]

What would be the solution, as I tried auto fill and it did not help?

Comment: to be more clear: it is close to this problem but I will not make drop list + I want to add them in separate tables to be able to print them .. ...https://superuser.com/questions/1279583/auto-populate-cells-in-excel?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The Answer posted by Mr.oldbrewer :
Thanks for his efforts ...
MOre organized: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1047030-auto-populate-specific-purpose-fill-small-tables-fixed-header-titles-data-organized-cells-post5027037.html#post5027037

name    class   degree  age percentage
A   5-E 5   20  90
B   6-A 10  22  10
C   2-A 20  23  50
D   5-E 30  24  60
E   4-A 40  22  70

NAME    DEGREE      ROW 10
A   5
PERCENTAGE  CLASS                   THIS SIMPLE EASY TO UNDERSTAND MACRO
90  5-E                 MAKES THE LAYOUT YOU WANT

NAME    DEGREE                  Sub Macro4()
B   10                  '
PERCENTAGE  CLASS                   ' Macro4 Macro
10  6-A                 ' Macro recorded 12/03/2018 by bob
                        '
NAME    DEGREE
C   20                  '
PERCENTAGE  CLASS                   J = 1
50  2-A                 For N = 10 To 30 Step 5
                        Cells(N, 1) = "NAME"
NAME    DEGREE                  Cells(N, 2) = "DEGREE"
D   30                  Cells(N + 2, 1) = "PERCENTAGE"
PERCENTAGE  CLASS                   Cells(N + 2, 2) = "CLASS"
60  5-E                 J = J + 1
                        Cells(N + 1, 1) = Cells(J, 1)
NAME    DEGREE                  Cells(N + 1, 2) = Cells(J, 3)
E   40                  Cells(N + 3, 1) = Cells(J, 5)
PERCENTAGE  CLASS                   Cells(N + 3, 2) = Cells(J, 2)
70  4-A                 Next N
                        End Sub